# Collapsing mixed types into a neat comma separated string

Tags: r

I have a list of mixed types which I would like to collapse into a neat comma separated string to be read somewhere else. The following is a MWE:

```
a <- "name"
b <- as.vector(c(10))
names(b) <- c('s')
c <- as.vector(c(1, 2))
names(c) <- c('p1', 'p2')
d <- 20
r <- list(a, b, c, d)
r
# [[1]]
# [1] "name"
# 
# [[2]]
#  s 
# 10 
# 
# [[3]]
# p1 p2 
#  1  2 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 20
```

I want this:

```
# [1] '"name","10","1,2","20"'
```

But this is as far as I got:

```
# Collapse individual elements into individual strings.
# `sapply` with `paste` works perfectly:
> sapply(r, paste, collapse = ",") 
# [1] "name" "10"   "1,2" "20"

# Try paste again (doesn't work):
> paste(sapply(r, paste, collapse = ","), collapse = ',')
# [1] "name,10,1,2,20"
```

I tried `paste0`, `cat` to no avail. The only way I could do it is using `write.table` and passing it a buffer memory. That way is too complicated, and quite error prone. I need to have my code working on a cluster with MPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the quotes - the ones printed after your `sapply` are just markers to show they are strings.  This seems to work...

```
cat(paste0('"',sapply(r, paste, collapse = ','),'"',collapse=','))

"name","10","1,2","20"
```

You might need to try with and without the `cat` if you are writing to a file.  Without it, at the terminal, you get backslashes before the 'real' quotes.